# sql query - I need to remove duplicate from query

Tags: mysql

How to select unique rows only 3: like this

```
63518 | 3 | 338 | 338 - Turks and .... | 0.0245 | 
63519 | 3 | 338 | 338 - Jamica         | 0.0235 | 
63522 | 3 | 338 | 338 - Haiti          | 0.0285 | 


SELECT 
    r.id,
    r.client_id,
    mcc.mcc AS mcc,
    CONCAT(mcc.mcc, " - ", mcc.country_name) AS mcc_text,
    r.rate,
    mcc.dial_code,
    r.active
 FROM rates r
    INNER JOIN clients c
    ON c.id = r.client_id
    INNER JOIN mcc
    ON mcc.mcc = r.mcc    
WHERE r.client_id = 3 AND r.mcc = 338 AND r.mnc = 50 AND r.active = 1
```

[image]

i tried to use 
....GROUP BY r.id
but mcc_text is wrong
[image]

Comment: use group by id  after where clause ends

Comment: @Abhishekkumar, i added pic , it doesn't worki ((

Comment: @shawnt00, i don't understand, ideal group is mcc_text = dial_code = id

Comment: @AxOn I was thinking that your screenshot was from data in table but I realized that's not the case. I believe the problem is that your join conditions are wrong. Hard to help without know what the data and tables look like though.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    r.id,
    r.client_id,
    mcc.mcc AS mcc,
    CONCAT(mcc.mcc, " - ", mcc.country_name) AS mcc_text,
    r.rate,
    mcc.dial_code,
    r.active
 FROM rates r
    INNER JOIN clients c
    ON c.id = r.client_id
    INNER JOIN mcc
    ON mcc.mcc = r.mcc    
WHERE r.client_id = 3 AND r.mcc = 338 AND r.mnc = 50 AND r.active = 1
```

Comment: result is same  like on may pic

Comment: using Distinct will not work as rate and dial code are different when id is same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query this may work

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    r.id,
    r.client_id,
    mcc.mcc AS mcc,
    CONCAT(mcc.mcc, " - ", mcc.country_name) AS mcc_text,    
    (SELECT rate FROM rates WHERE rates.id=r.id)AS rate,
    mcc.dial_code,
    r.active
 FROM rates r
    INNER JOIN clients c
    ON c.id = r.client_id
    INNER JOIN mcc
    ON mcc.mcc = r.mcc    
WHERE r.client_id = 3 AND r.mcc = 338 AND r.mnc = 50 AND r.active = 1
GROUP BY r.id
```

Comment: 20:46:01 Note: 1276. Field or reference 'smpp.r.mcc' of SELECT #2 was resolved in SELECT #1